# SUM function in a case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

The below query is executed on a table with 2 fields:BEGDATE and AMOUNT (both varchar2).
 the aim is to display the data as follow:

```
 Year  Semester Total
 2017   Sem1     545
 2017   Sem2     9877
 2020   Sem1     444
```

The idea is to calculate the total of the field amount based on the year and semester.
 The below query is able to return the following:

```
 Year  Semester 
 2017   Sem1     
 2017   Sem2     
 2020   Sem1
```

Where should I use `SUM(TO_NUMBER(AMOUNT))` to be able to attain the desired outcome?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR (BEGDATE, 1, 4)) AS YEAR,
       CASE
          WHEN SUBSTR (BEGDATE, 5, 2) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
             THEN 'SEM1'
          WHEN SUBSTR (BEGDATE, 5, 2)  BETWEEN 4 AND 6
             THEN 'SEM2'
          WHEN SUBSTR (BEGDATE, 5, 2)  BETWEEN 7 AND 9
             THEN 'SEM3'
          ELSE 'SEM4'
       END SEMESTER
  FROM EMP 
  ORDER BY YEAR DESC,SEMESTER
```

Comment: You should use appropriate datatypes, if you want to store dates, use a `date(time)` datatype, if you want to store a number, use a numeric datatype. It's what they are there for! The sum you can just add as another selected attribute, don't forget to `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a sum at the end of select column list will do it.

```
SELECT   SUBSTR (begdate, 1, 4) AS YEAR,
         CASE
            WHEN SUBSTR (begdate, 5, 2) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
               THEN 'SEM1'
            WHEN SUBSTR (begdate, 5, 2) BETWEEN 4 AND 6
               THEN 'SEM2'
            WHEN SUBSTR (begdate, 5, 2) BETWEEN 7 AND 9
               THEN 'SEM3'
            ELSE 'SEM4'
         END semester,
         SUM (TO_NUMBER (amount)) sum_val
    FROM emp
GROUP BY SUBSTR (begdate, 1, 4),
         CASE
            WHEN SUBSTR (begdate, 5, 2) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
               THEN 'SEM1'
            WHEN SUBSTR (begdate, 5, 2) BETWEEN 4 AND 6
               THEN 'SEM2'
            WHEN SUBSTR (begdate, 5, 2) BETWEEN 7 AND 9
               THEN 'SEM3'
            ELSE 'SEM4'
         END
ORDER BY YEAR DESC, semester;
```

Moreover you don't need the distinct any more as you are doing group by.

Comment: Are we going to teach JDOE online, or has he attended a basic SQL development course?

Comment: Yeah, this is everything that's wrong with SO, and other help-by-gamification sites like it (expertsexchange). I'll give you a fiver to do my homework for me

Answer (score 0):

Added `SUM`

```
SELECT A.YEAR,A.SEMESTER, SUM(TO_NUMBER(A.AMOUNT)) AS SUM_AMT
FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR (BEGDATE, 1, 4)) AS YEAR,
       CASE
          WHEN SUBSTR (BEGDATE, 5, 2) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
             THEN 'SEM1'
          WHEN SUBSTR (BEGDATE, 5, 2)  BETWEEN 4 AND 6
             THEN 'SEM2'
          WHEN SUBSTR (BEGDATE, 5, 2)  BETWEEN 7 AND 9
             THEN 'SEM3'
          ELSE 'SEM4'
       END SEMESTER,
AMOUNT
  FROM EMP 
  ORDER BY YEAR DESC,SEMESTER)A
GROUP BY YEAR,SEMESTER
ORDER BY YEAR DESC, SEMESTER;
```